# How to run a command inside shell script only once

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have written bash shell script, which will download artifact and untar it and copy it to the destination folder.
After that it does some more steps.
and i am running this script from mco command which will execute in many hosts parallely. but i want restrict one perticular command to execute only once.
how do i do that.
except that command all other should execute in all host

myscript.sh :

```
if [ "$#" -eq 2 ]; then   
    Name=$1
    version=$2
    tarname=$Name"-"$version-SNAPSHOT.tar
    SNAPSHOT=$Name-$version-SNAPSHOT
    if [[ ! -e "/<path>/$tarname" && "/<path>/$SNAPSHOT" ]]; then

       do something  // this command i want to execute only once or only in one host. 
    fi
```

I execute this script like this :

```
mco shellcmd '/path/myscript.sh name version' -I /host-10[012345]/
```

this script executes in 50 host at a time but one particulate command should execute in only one host/one time.

how do we do this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the hostname:

```
if [[ "$HOSTNAME" == "foobar" ]]; then
  echo "execute command here"
fi
```